# Adding new Principled BSDF materials using python scripting

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to add a new principled bsdf material using this code :

```
import bpy

newmat = bpy.data.materials.new("VertCol")
newmat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = newmat.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes

bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF") 

bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value
bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value
bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value[:]
(0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 0.800000011920929, 1.0)

bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (1, 0, 0, 1)
bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].keyframe_insert("default_value", frame=80)
True

bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (0,  0, 1, 1)
bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].keyframe_insert("default_value", frame=81)
True
```

but I got an error which is :
`KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Material" not found'` in line 11.
Line 11 is `bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value`

any tips? thank you

Answer (score 2):

[`bpy.data.materials`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.materials) contains materials, each of which have a name. In your script, you created a new material using `bpy.data.materials.new("VertCol")`, requesting the name `VertCol`. The new material is therefore going to be named `VertCol`, or if that already existed, `VertCol.NNN` where `NNN` is a number 001 or higher. Then using `bpy.data.materials['Material']` you tried to access a material named `Material`. Presumably that came from recording the script from actions.

To clean up the script, replace explicitly named references like that with variable references:

```
bpy.data.materials['Material'] = newmat
bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"] = bsdf
```

Also, lines like `bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value` or `True` read a value but do nothing with it. They can simply be removed. It appears the script contains a mix of inputs and outputs from the interactive console.